# Unterminated object at jsonobject line 19?

Tags: java, android, json

Am new to android development am making simple login application using volley and getting json response from server like this:

json response:-

```
 {"loginResult":"{\"UserLoginID\":864,\"UserID\":864,\"EmployeeCode\":\"PI4264\",\"Password\":\"XXXX\",\"IsPasswordChanged\":false,\"ModuleName\":\"XXX\",\"ModuleID\":1,\"EmployeeName\":\"XXXX  \"}"}
```

When i try to parse this jsonobect am getting :

Unterminated object at 19 jsonexception so far what i have tried is to parse is

```
 String resp = response.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "");

                    try {
                        JSONObject yog = new JSONObject(resp);
                        int yogs=yog.getInt("UserID");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

don't know where am making mistake can anybody teach me am i doing it in right way!!!

Comment: The server returns a uh, cruel and unusual data structure (Json-Object inside a Json-String). Any chance to change the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an un-necessary string sanitization.
Just remove `replaceAll` command. and use following code :

```
try {
    JSONObject yog = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject loginObject = new JSONObject(yog.getString("loginResult")); 
    int yogs=loginObject.getInt("UserID");
    System.out.println(yogs);
    }
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should work fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to this:

```
String resp = response.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "");
                    try {
                        JSONObject yog = new JSONObject(resp);
                        JSONObject loginObject = new JSONObject(yog.getString("loginResult")); 
                        int yogs=loginObject.getInt("UserID");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I executed the code and didn't get the error:

```
JSONObject yog = new JSONObject("{\"loginResult\":\"{\\\"UserLoginID\\\":864,\\\"UserID\\\":864,\\\"EmployeeCode\\\":\\\"PI4264\\\"," +
                        "\\\"Password\\\":\\\"XXXX\\\",\\\"IsPasswordChanged\\\":false,\\\"ModuleName\\\":\\\"XXX\\\",\\\"ModuleID\\\":1,\\\"EmployeeName\\\":\\\"XXXX " +
                        "\\\"}\"}");
JSONObject loginObject = new JSONObject(yog.getString("loginResult"));
int yogs=loginObject.getInt("UserID");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(yogs), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: See my edit. If you `resp` variable contains the response you have mentioned in the question. This should work fine.

Comment: Is the replaceAll really necessary?